# Why is my console giving me a bunch of error messages on Sublime?

Tags: console, sublimetext3, sublime-anaconda

After downloading Terminus (I don't know whether this has anything to do with the problem) in Sublime Text 3 I notice that when I pressed "ctrl+`" it opened the console and displayed a ton of error messages. What's going on here and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Here's the error:

```
Make sure your interpreter is a valid binary and is in your PATH or use an absolute path to it, for example: C:\\Python27\\python.exe
 ...last message repeated one more time in the last 10s
ERROR:root:Your operating system denied the spawn of /usr/local/bin/python3 process. Make sure your configured interpreter is a valid python binary executable and is in the PATH
The OS did return [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
anacondaST3: ERROR - <Anaconda.anaconda_lib.workers.local_process.LocalProcess object at 0x0000017199588518> process can not start a new anaconda JsonServer in the operating system because:
Anaconda can not spawn a new process with your current configured python interpreter (/usr/local/bin/python3)
Make sure your interpreter is a valid binary and is in your PATH or use an absolute path to it, for example: C:\\Python27\\python.exe
anacondaST3: ERROR - <Anaconda.anaconda_lib.workers.local_process.LocalProcess object at 0x00000171991DFDA0> process can not start a new anaconda JsonServer in the operating system because:
Anaconda can not spawn a new process with your current configured python interpreter (/usr/local/bin/python3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is related to the [`Anaconda`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Anaconda) plugin, not Terminus. You need to set the path to your default Python interpreter. If you don't know it already, hit <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> then type in `cmd` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. In the window that opens up, type in

```
where python
```

and one or more lines will print out, assuming that you already have Python installed and in your `PATH`. Make note of the first line.

Next, go back to Sublime and go to **`Preferences → Package Settings → Anaconda → Settings—User`**. If the file is *not* empty, add the line

```json
"python_interpreter": "c:/path/to/python.exe",
```

replacing `path/to/` with the actual path. You can either use single forward slashes `/` as path delimiters, or you can use double backslashes `\\`. Just don't use single backslashes, as that may cause problems.

If the user preferences file doesn't have anything in it, set its contents to the following:

```json
{
    "python_interpreter": "c:/path/to/python.exe",
}
```

Save the file, and hopefully the error messages should go away. If you want to configure anything else about Anaconda while you're there, open up **`Preferences → Package Settings → Anaconda → Settings—Default`** and copy over any keys you want to customize. Just make sure each line ends with a comma `,`. The last line doesn't have to, but it won't hurt anything if it does.